# For each $\epsilon>0$ there is such $\delta>0$, s.t. $|x-x_0|<\epsilon$ $\Rightarrow$ $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\delta$. What does it mean?

Tags: calculus, limits

We know  that $\lim_\limits{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$ means that: for each $\epsilon>0$ there is such $\delta>0$, s.t. $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$ $\Rightarrow$ $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$.

what does the following expression mean?

for each $\epsilon>0$ there is such $\delta>0$, s.t. $|x-x_0|<\epsilon$ $\Rightarrow$ $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\delta$.

- Is $f$ continuous at $x_0$?
- What quality of $f$ does the above-mentioned definition describe?

The lecturer gave is this new definition and told us to think about it, is that some kind of introduction to Uniform Continuity?

Comment: By continuous at $a$, do you mean $x_0?$

Comment: Between the two statements, $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are permuted. Is it on purpose?

Comment: yes! its on purpose. and I corrected the $a$.

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani I apologize for my earlier response. The comment was true. This is not the definition of absolute continuity; $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are reversed.

Answer (score 3):

What it states is that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that the value of $f$ on the interval $]x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon[$ is in the interval $]f(x_0) - \delta, f(x_0) + \delta[$.

The answer is that $f$ does not have to be continuous at $x_0$. Can you see why?

Comment: are you implying that it still can be not continuous and has like a value which is not on the graph put jumping a little bit higher but still this value inside the intercal $[f(x_0)-\delta, f(x_0)+\delta]$ ?

Comment: For example. $f$ could or could not be continuous. Really the values can be anything as long as they are on the interval $]f(x_0) - \delta, f(x_0) + \delta[$, so there is no reason to expect continuity.

Answer (score 2):

There are many exercises based on randomly modifying the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit to see what properties of a function they define.  This is one of them.

The modification here is that the roles of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are reversed.  The condition is stronger for *larger* $\epsilon$.   It is saying that $f$ is bounded on larger and larger intervals surrounding $x_0$, and in fact is bounded on every finite interval.  Two things to notice are that this property is weaker than being bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ and that it does not depend on $x_0$ although the definition was stated with $x_0$.

Nobody would express boundedness on finite intervals in this way deliberately, it is only for purposes of exercise on the definition of limit.

Answer (score 0):

**$f$ might not be continuous.**
Take the example of the function defined as $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x= 0\\
\sin \frac{1}{x} & \text{ else}
\end{cases}$$
$f$ satisfies your criteria at $0$ (with $\delta=2$ for all $\epsilon$).

**$f$ is always locally bounded at $x_0$.**

Comment: It is not a local property, although it looks like that at first.

Comment: @zyx I don't understand your comment. $x_0$ seems to be fixed and $f$ is bounded in the neightborhood of $x_0$.

Comment: In arbitrarily large neighborhoods of x_0, so not dependent on x_0.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of defining limits, suppose $|f(x_0)|< \infty.$

Now consider all $x$ within some vicinity ($\epsilon$) of $x_0.$ The condition states that for these $x,$ the values of $f(x)$ differ from $f(x_0)$ by at most $\delta.$ Now $\epsilon$ can be any positive number, so this means $f$ cannot be "infinite distance" from $f(x_0),$ if that makes sense, except when $|x|=\infty$. In other words, $f$ is bounded near $x_0$ (near meaning within finite distance from it). So basically, the statement implies $|f(x)|<\infty$ when $|x|<\infty.$

Also, this does not imply $f$ is continuous. Consider, for example,
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if } x \leq x_0 \\1 &\mbox{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$ Clearly, $f(x)$ is locally bounded (in fact, globally bounded), but isn't continuous.

Comment: I think nothing is said about $f$, except that epsilon delta implication.

Comment: Well the epsilon delta implication also implies {$B(x_0,\epsilon) \Rightarrow B(f(x_0),\delta)$} which means $|f(x)|$ cannot be $\infty$ for all $x\in B(x_0,\epsilon).$ But now epsilon is any positive number, so that means $|f(x)|$ cannot be $\infty$ for all $x$ that is within finite distance from $x_0.$

Comment: I would agree that $f$ having finite values makes life easier, because assigning a meaningful value for $\lvert f(x) - f(x_0)\rvert$ for something like $f(x) = -\infty$ or dismissing it, is problematic. I would not go so far to say that such an $f$ is excluded.